# Android check for fingerprint scanner is available

Tags: android

If fingerprint scanner is available let user use my apps feature by authenticating with fingerprint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this code:

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) { 
    // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
} else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
    // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
} else { 
    // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
}
```

Comment: It is deprecated now. You should use BiometricPrompt

Answer (score 0):

[Try `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_FINGERPRINT) on a `PackageManager` instance (you can get one from calling `getPackageManager()` on any handy `Context`).

Comment: looks like a copy of @CommonsWare response, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35302139/869451